# How I make this mysql `SELECT` query?

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables one for 'district' and other one for 'province'. My table structure is

**district -** `district_id, province_id, district`

**province -** `province_id, province`

My question is how I make a query when I available a `district_id`?

I tried it something like this, but it selecting all the provinces.

```
SELECT province
FROM province, district
WHERE district.district_id = 5
```

Hope somebody may help me out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM province p INNER JOIN district d ON p.province_id = d.province_id
WHERE d.district_id = 5
```

Explanation:
The letters p and d after the table names are just aliases. It allows you to just type the single letter rather than the full table name when you reference the table. You can choose what to use for an alias (i.e. they didn't have to be p and d), within certain rules (such as no SQL keywords).

Use a JOIN statement to specify how two tables relate to each other. In this case, rows in the province table relate to rows in the district table where they have a matching province_id.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
 Select p.* From province p,district d Where d.district_id=5 and p.province_id=d.province_id
```